# Separate strings file for HTML content

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have all constants in an HTML (such as strings and numbers) be separated into a separate file?  That is, instead of

```
<title>Hello World</title>
```

do something like

```
<title>STR_TITLE</title>
```

and another file, declare

```
STR_TITLE = "Hello World"
```

I am currently  using global Javascript variables and using document.write() in the HTML code, but looking for a better solution.

I think it would be easier way to separate the content in an easy to read/use file, so non-developers can go in and change the content whenever they like.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few available libraries to help with this, here's one:

[{{ mustache }}](http://mustache.github.com/)

and another:

[ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/)

And all these:

[microjs.com/#templating](http://microjs.com/#templating)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use handlebars, or underscore.js